# Can't access internal storage from normal system but I can in TWRP?

Tags: internal-storage, twrp

I have Lenovo K3 Note and I flash NEXUS-V2.5 rom. System works fine I think but I can't access anything through file managers,sdcard, sdcard0, sdcard1 are empty, but they have files on them, which are available when I boot in TWRP. TWRP version is 2.8.6.0. When I try to push files from adb I get error `Read-only file system`. adb works fine in recovery.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: Can I install custom rom and custom recovery TWRP if I am not root?

Comment: Yes, I am rooted.

Comment: @dukasvili Yes, as a recovery can also be installed from a computer, and yes, because not every ROM comes pre-rooted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute following commands via ADB if you are rooted (in what I strongly doubt):

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

or

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o remount,rw /system"
```

After that your `push` should work.
If you are not rooted, you will fail on the second command. If so firstly you should acquire root on your phone.

What concerning your question about customs ROMs/recovery: most custom ROMs already contain root patches. However, flashing TWRP has nothing to do with root and is done separately.

Comment: I don't know what I done but I now have access to internal memory from OS.
I tried to flash another rom and that get stuck on boot logo and I flash first rom second time and now is working. I  thought that unlocking bootloader is same as rooting, my mistake...

Comment: Cool! Anyway anyhow the job is done:)